# Is it possible to retrieve every record after one with a certain ID?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I'm using MySQL and want to sort a table alphabetically by the column 'name' and then retrieve all records after a record whose 'id' is, say, 10.

Can this be done? What would the query look like?

Comment: Did you not just ask something very similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148365/how-to-retrieve-all-records-after-one-with-an-id-in-symfony, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148913/how-to-convert-this-mysql-statement-to-symfony-propel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a subquery?

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable`
    WHERE `name` > (SELECT name FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` = 10)
    ORDER BY `name`
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is the PK...

```
SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE 'id'>10 ORDER BY 'name'
```

according to nathan's interpretation of the question...

```
ALTER TABLE 'mytable' ORDER BY 'name';
SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE 'id'>10;
```

According to OP's requirements:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'mytable' ORDER BY 'name'";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query, $connection));

while($row = $result) {
  if ($row['id'] != 10) {
    array_shift($result);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

then `$result` is your final response :)

Comment: The next id in the list of records returned could be a smaller value than the current one so this doesn't work.