# How to retrieve all records after one with an ID in symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, symfony-1.4

Let's say I have a table that I sort alphabetically in symfony. Each item has a rather random id and I'd like to retrieve all items after a certain ID. For example:

```
Name      ID
------------
Apple     5
Banana    9
Coconut   3
Date      1
Eggplant  8
```

Let's say I wanted to retrieve `Date` and `Eggplant`. I know beforehand of the ID 3 and that I want everything after it.

How should I construct the statements to achieve this?

I don't care if the answer uses Propel, MySQL, SQL, or whatever. As long as it's possible.

Comment: Can you give some better details?  You know the ID# and you want everything after it?  Everything after what?  The ID of Date or Eggplant?  Alphabetically what comes after Date?  I just don't see what you're asking for.

Comment: @JustAguy: Yes, the ID 3 would be hardcoded. I want everything after the ID of 3 (Coconut), after it is sorted alphabetically. The query would return the `Date` and `Eggplant` records in this scenario. Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: is the column name `NAME` has index on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE name > (
  SELECT name
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE id = 3
)
ORDER BY name
```

(runs at least with Postgres and with Just Aguy's SQL Fiddle)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but is there any way to get it to ignore Coconut? I only want it to return Date and Eggplant. Also, would you happen to know the symfony equivalent of that statement?

Comment: @Benjamin M - You need `ORDER BY Name` in the outer query to get the result exactly the way OP wants it.

Comment: It ignores the entry with id=3. Have you tested it? .. I've never ever used symfony. sorry.

Comment: @PM77-1: the query without the `ORDER` clause will still produce the right results, just with a different ordering.

Comment: @John Smith - Benjamin's code would not return 'Cocunut'. See this Fiddle (borrowed from Just Guy): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca77d/1
Just Guy's solution uses different values for ID and that's why he has a different result.

Comment: @Benjamin M - Yes, you have the right solution "as is". I was nitpicking on the exact order of the result only.

Comment: Is it possible to convert this statement to a Propel one?

Comment: I don't know Propel. But maybe have a look here: http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2007/06/12/propel-queries-using-custom-sql-peer-classes-and-criterion-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f00f/4) that shows this working.  The query is simple, just do some matching on the first letter.  I don't like the idea of the hardcoded value of 3 being there.  Is there a process that's going to set the value of the id?

```
    select name from tbl1 
    where (Left(name,1)) > (select Left(name,1) 
                        from tbl1 where id = 3)
    order by name asc
```

Comment: But your query has a little problem: You will also retrieve the `name` with id=3. The question says `I know beforehand of the ID 3 and that I want everything **after it**.`

Comment: But it doesn't work if there are 2 entries with the same first letter!

Comment: Look here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c42c5/1/0 . `Bubabing` should also get returned