# How to convert this MySQL statement to symfony Propel?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, symfony-1.4

Here's the MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE name > (
  SELECT name
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE id = 3
)
ORDER BY name
```

Here's my best guess at the Propel code but it's not working:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(CartPeer::ITEM_NAME);
$c->add(CartPeer::CATEGORY, $c->add(CartPeer::ITEM_ID, $item->getItemId()), Criteria::GREATER_THAN);
```

In respond to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148365/how-to-retrieve-all-records-after-one-with-an-id-in-symfony#15148613)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propel doesn't have a *standard* way of doing subqueries as part of a criteria.

You can either separate your query (obtain the value you want to compare against first and then use it into the original query) or use a `CUSTOM` criteria with your subquery in your propel query.

Here's an example of the second option:

```
$c = new Criteria();

$subSelect = "cart.category > (
  SELECT cart.category
  FROM carts
  WHERE carts.id = 3)";

$c->add(CartPeer::CATEGORY, $subSelect, Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

**EDIT:** Here's an example of the first option

```
// find the object we want to compare against
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(CartPeer::ID, 3); 
$cart = CartPeer::doSelectOne($c)

// then make the actual criteria
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(CartPeer::CATEGORY, $cart->getCategory(), Criteria::GREATER_THAN)
```

The only problem with this option is that you are making *two queries* instead of one, which may hit on your performance, but it depends on your application of course.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of the first option?

Comment: Give me a little while and I'll add an example for it too :3

Comment: Thanks. One problem, though, is that I don't think I have a `CartQuery`. I have `CartPeer` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Oh, probably the version of Propel you use doesn't have the `*Query` classes. I updated the answer using only `*Peer` and `Criteria`